# What's included in Frecciabianca 1st class?

Tags: trains, italy, luxury, trenitalia

I'm going to travel with [Frecciabianca](https://www.italiarail.com/frecciabianca) in [1st class](https://www.italiarail.com/rail-passes/what-difference-between-1st-and-2nd-class) in a few days and I wonder what I can expect so that I can prepare correctly.

- Will there be lounge access at Roma Termini?
- Will there be free espresso or prosecco?
- Is there any kind of kiosk in the 1st class car?
- Is the 1st class car free of noisy travellers?

On the trains I take here in Sweden it's yes on all of these points (except no prosecco).

Comment: "Is the 1st class car free of noisy travellers?" - no. People who have a bit more money are just as, or even more, obnoxious as us lowly poor earthlings. Italians aren't known for being particularly quiet, too.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar in general 1st class is quieter due to families with kids will more rarely use them.

Comment: Where do I get my complimentary prosecco in Swedish första klass??

Comment: @ToivoSäwén you don't, it's against the law since it's also being sold for money at the same establishment. But there's usually a thermos with coffee in one end of the car together with some snacks. Even a small kitchen but always unattended.

Comment: None of this is terribly common elsewhere in Europe. When some of these services are availble it's usually as part of some super-premium / executive / business fare or for frequent travellers. First class means larger seat and usually calmer carriage (fewer people, fewer families or teenagers due to the price), that's it.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder why would it be against the law to give a free glass of X if it’s also sold there? Restaurants do that all the time

Comment: @MattDouhan it is in Sweden.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Really? When I owned a restaurant we always gave free welcoming drinks even though we sold the same drink as well, is this train specific?

Comment: @MattDouhan no, only hotels have special laws. Either the drinks are free, or not free. If you sell alcoholic beverages the customers must always pay for them. You can however use a coupon system for drinks to circumvent it.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder weird never heard of that rule in my life

Comment: @MattDouhan from the Swedish law *"Priset för en alkoholdryck får vid servering inte sättas lägre än inköpspriset för drycken jämte skäligt påslag."*. The price must be at least the purchase price and must also have a margin. And, *"Gästerna får inte uppmanas eller förmås att köpa alkoholdrycker."* guests must not be encouraged to buy alcoholic drinks.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder that’s just funny I do understand swedish but had no idea about this law and for sure have broken it when I owned a restaurant there.

Comment: @MattDouhan then I don't know how you got your License to Serve since you have to answer questions about that law.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder that’s why I am so surprised as well about never hearing about it, have not lived in sweden for close to 30 years now though so shrug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Turns out things might have changed, if the sources in the other answers once were right.*

The differences are these:

- Better seats in a 1+2 configuration.
- Dedicated 1st class conductor.
- All cars are closer to the restaurant car.

And most likely because there are generally fewer passengers:

- More storage space.
- Less noise.
- Better WC access and state.
- Faster boarding.

The 1+2 configuration is used cleverly by the booking system and solo passengers will get a solo seat, dual passengers will get seats facing each other in the 1 row when available and the quad seating will be left for groups of 3 or 4.

What's **not** included is complimentary drinks and snacks. I was a bit disappointed when I found this out. There's also no lounge access included nor fast track.

---

*Source: travelled with Frecciabianca 1st class when writing this answer and talked with the restaurant staff.*