# What's Trenitalia's best class?

Tags: trains, italy, luxury, trenitalia

I wonder which class is the best, where you have the best seats, most services included for free, on the train, fast track, lounge etc? Why I wonder is because [I was pretty disappointed by the 1st class in Frecciabianca](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/144079/18374).

I have seen pictures of seats like the ones below but I don't even know which class that is or what's included.

[image: Some better seats Trenitalia has]

Comment: From a reverse google search, that's apparently the "Executive" class .https://italy4travellers.com/the-guide-to-the-italian-train-system/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Man in Seat 61 has a [guide to Italy's railway](https://www.seat61.com/Italy.htm). The photo in the question appears to be from the [Frecciarossa 1000](https://www.seat61.com/frecciarossa.htm). Frecciarossa trains have four classes. The highest "Executive Class" is described as follows:

> Executive class consists of just 8 super-comfortable leather reclining seats at one end of the train with their own dedicated steward or stewardess. Power sockets at all seats. The fare includes a complimentary cold tray meal (or snack, on shorter runs) and alcoholic and non-alcoholic drinks, and all Executive passengers can use the Frecciaclub first class lounges at main stations. Executive class also features a 6-seat meeting room.

However, it is also extremely expensive. The next two lower classes, Business and Premium both come with a welcome drink, but no complementary meal. Lounge access is also not included [unless you book a Business class *Salottino*](https://www.trenitalia.com/en/services/frecciaclub.html), which is a business class seat in a compartment rather than in the open carriage.

> #### Who has the right of admission
>
> Entry is reserved for holders of CartaFRECCIA Oro and Platino cards who have or intend to buy a ticket, and to those who have Executive, Business salottino tickets or are holders of a 10-journey Carnet for 1st/Business/Executive class with reservation. The holder of a CartaFRECCIA Base card may enter by purchasing a half-yearly or yearly season ticket or a 10-entry carnet.

Comment: How much is an Executive ticket from say Milan to Rome?

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica ~EUR 155 one way.

Answer (score 1):

In Italy the main train companies are two: Italo and Trenitalia.

Trenitalia covers quite 100% of italian stations and have different kind of trains.
*regionale* and *intercity* are the two less expensive that covers both long legs and short distances (about long legs: are cheaper but takes like **forever** because stops quite in every station, for istance venice-rome with *regionale* it's about 8 hours and 4 changes).
*freccie* are the trains for long legs, less stops, faster and more confortable. There are three types of *frecce*: *argento*, *bianca* and *rossa*: [here a detailed description from trainline site](https://www.thetrainline.com/en/train-companies/trenitalia/trenitalia-frecce) (in fact it's a translation of the italian version you can find [here from trenitalia site](https://www.trenitalia.com/it/le_frecce.html) which is in italian, sorry i can't find the correspoding page in english in the official site...). In this trains you will find the better quality, and in *freccia rossa* the best (like the exclusive in your picture).

About italo, it covers the main legs (it's expanding it's offer) and have basically 4 classes: smart, confort, prima and club exclusive [here a description from italo site](https://www.italotreno.it/en/the-train)

You can find other companies, but they cover small legs and only regional, the quality of service is usually similar of trenitalia regionale/intercity because are used for short times/distances and are usually "specialized" in particular routes (for example [trenord](https://www.trenord.it/EN/) for lombardia region and milan malpensa airport).

**Edit**: Be aware that if you need to go, for example, venice-rome you can buy venice-milan from italo and milan-rome from trenitalia but since are different companyes if the first train (for some reason) it's late, the second won't wait for you (and if you don't have a tiket that let's you to change day/time you also will loose the money)...if you buy all the leg **in one single tiket** from the same company, in case of delay or the second train will wait for you, or you will be able to catch the train after with the same tiket (in this case is better to explain to the conductor that you missed the previous because of a delay showing the tiket as soon as you take the train) - thay are oblied to give you a solution if the missed coincidence it's caused by them if you buyed a single tiket for the leg.